# Get function name from function address

Tags: binary

As the question states, I have a function address and want to analyze my binary to find its function name. Is there a tool to do that? I have both binary and symbols.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean you have both the assembled binary object file and the symbols table and want to find out the name of a function from its virtual address in the symbols table? I'm pretty sure this is impossible. Though, I guess it would depend on the compiler you used, and whether it chooses to keep these data.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows in native code, you can use [SymFromAddr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681323(VS.85).aspx) in the dbghelp library to find out the symbol name.  This does require you to have debug symbols for the binary.  If you don't have any symbol information, you won't be able to find out the name of the function just from the binary itself.

It is also possible for one address to correspond to multiple functions - if several functions compile to the same machine code the linker may combine them together into a single piece of code in the binary.